# CORS From jQuery Succeeds But Fails With AngularJs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, spring, cors

I have my Java Spring API with CORS enabled to which I want to make call using AngularJS. I first wrote a demo jQuery code to test CORS and it worked perfectly. Then I wrote an equivalent AngularJS code which always produces the same error -

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/my_project_name/api/get_some_data. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

On researching about making CORS requests from AngularJS most results say that no changes are required in AngularJS when making CORS requests, but it doesn't seem to work. Is there anything I'm doing wrong or missing? BTW I'm using AngularJS v1.3.15.

Following is how I have enabled CORS in the Spring application (`BaseWebConfig` extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`) -

```
public class WebConfig extends BaseWebConfig {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
        ResourceHttpMessageConverter resourceHttpMessageConverter = new ResourceHttpMessageConverter();
        converters.add(resourceHttpMessageConverter);
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        // allow cross-origin API requests
        registry
                .addMapping("/api/**")
                .allowedMethods(
                        HttpMethod.GET.name(),
                        HttpMethod.HEAD.name(),
                        HttpMethod.POST.name(),
                        HttpMethod.PUT.name(),
                        HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name())
                .allowCredentials(false);
    }

}
```

I first testing CORS using a jQuery code as follows which runs perfectly -

```
$(function() {
                $('#submit_jquery').click(function() {
                    var token = $('#token').val().trim();
                    var headerValue = "Bearer " + token;
                    var body = $('#body').val().trim();
                    var domain = $('#api_domain').val().trim();
                    $('#result').text('');
                    $.ajax({
                        method : 'POST',
                        url : domain + '/api/get_some_data',
                        contentType : 'application/json',
                        data : body,
                        beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", headerValue);
                        },
                        success : function(json) {
                            console.log('success');
                            $('#result').html('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 2) + '</pre>');
                        },
                        error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log('error');
                        },
                        complete : function() {
                            console.log('complete');
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
```

Then I wrote an equivalent AngularJS code as follows -

```
app.controller('CorsController', ['$scope', '$http',
                function($scope, $http) {
                    $scope.makeCorsRequest = function() {
                        var token = $('#token').val().trim();
                        var headerValue = "Bearer " + token;
                        var body = $('#body').val().trim();
                        var domain = $('#api_domain').val().trim();
                        var url = domain + '/api/get_some_data';
                        var header = {'Authorization': headerValue, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'};

                        $http({
                            method: 'POST',
                            url: url,
                            header: header,
                            data: body
                        }).then(
                                //success callback
                                function (data) {
                                    console.log('SUCCESS');
                                    console.log(data);
                                },
                                //error callback
                                function (errorMessage) {
                                    console.error('ERROR');
                                    console.error(errorMessage);
                                }
                        );
                    };
                }]);
```

The API response header when call is made from jQuery is as follows. Two calls are made by browser actually -

Header of first response -

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:accept, authorization, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:1800
Allow:GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Content-Length:0
Date:Mon, 28 Mar 2016 10:30:00 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Vary:Origin
```

Header of second response -

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Mon, 28 Mar 2016 10:30:00 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Origin
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't enabled CORS yet.
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is required in header to be set as `*` for CORS.

Try with  `.allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8000");` or better use `.allowedOrigins("*");`.
You can read up on this at https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

From `401`, I believe there is some error in authentication. Use `headers` instead of `header` as given below and check if this works.

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: header, //use headers here
    data: body
})
```

Comment: Can you show the API response headers in this case? You can use chrome debugger tool for this.

Comment: I have update the question with the required details.

Comment: Header is fine now. Are you getting `401` as HTTP status code?

Comment: From the jQuery request, both calls have 200 status. From Angular, yes I get 401.

Comment: 401 implies authentication error. Check the updated answer.

Comment: It worked! It was a typo. For AngularJS its should have been `headers` (like you suggested) instead of `header`. Thanks!